# How can i combine data in array with common key

Tags: ansible

I use ansible and I have an array which contains some data with duplicate key. It's look like:

```
[        {
            "key1": {
                "path": "sadasdasdsa",
                "user": "user1"
            }
        },
        {
            "key1": {
                "path": "nBoDuqWRRoZ3LvU1wO",
                "user": "user1"
            }
        },
        {
            "key2": {
                "path": "fwefwfewfwf",
                "user": "user2"
            }
        },
        {
            "key2": {
                "path": "gfdgdfg",
                "user": "user2"
            }
        }    ]
```

I need convert it to array without duplicated keys. I want to combaine data with common keys. It should be

```
[        {
            "key1": {
                [ 
                    {
                    "path": "sadasdasdsa",
                    "user": "user1"
                    },
                    {
                    "path": "nBoDuqWRRoZ3LvU1wO",
                    "user": "user1"
                    }
                ]   
        },
        {
            "key2": {
                [
                    {
                    "path": "fwefwfewfwf",
                    "user": "user2"
                    },
                    {
                    "path": "gfdgdfg",
                    "user": "user2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }    ]
```

How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the array is stored in the variable *array1*, the task below

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        array2: "{{ array2|default([]) + [{item.0: _list}] }}"
      loop: "{{ array1|map('dict2items')|map('first')|groupby('key') }}"
      vars:
        _list: "{{ item.1|json_query('[].value') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  array2:
  - key1:
    - path: sadasdasdsa
      user: user1
    - path: nBoDuqWRRoZ3LvU1wO
      user: user1
  - key2:
    - path: fwefwfewfwf
      user: user2
    - path: gfdgdfg
      user: user2
```

---

You can get a dictionary, instead of the list, if you *combine* the items. Replacing the line e.g.

```yaml
          dict2: "{{ dict2|default({})|combine({item.0: _list}) }}"
```

would give the dictionary

```yaml
  dict2:
    key1:
    - path: sadasdasdsa
      user: user1
    - path: nBoDuqWRRoZ3LvU1wO
      user: user1
    key2:
    - path: fwefwfewfwf
      user: user2
    - path: gfdgdfg
      user: user2
```

Answer (score 0):

An other option without using a task with the `json_query` filter in the equation.

***Note**: the apparently useless `map('list')` in the series of filters is mandatory until the [following jmespath merge request](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.py/pull/180) is accepted.*

**Demo playbook:**

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    # Your orig data as json on a single line for compactness
    test_var: [{"key1": {"path": "sadasdasdsa", "user": "user1"}}, {"key1": {"path": "nBoDuqWRRoZ3LvU1wO", "user": "user1"}}, {"key2": {"path": "fwefwfewfwf", "user": "user2"}}, {"key2": {"path": "gfdgdfg", "user": "user2"}}]

    transform_query: >-
      [*].{key: @[0], value: @[1][].value}

    transformed_var:  >-
      {{
        test_var
        | map('dict2items')
        | flatten
        | groupby('key')
        | map('list')
        | json_query(transform_query)
        | items2dict
      }}

  tasks:
    - name: Show our transformed var
      debug:
        var: transformed_var
```

**Result:**

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [Show our transformed var] ************************************************
Thursday 08 April 2021  12:37:07 +0200 (0:00:00.023)       0:00:00.023 ******** 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "transformed_var": {
        "key1": [
            {
                "path": "sadasdasdsa",
                "user": "user1"
            },
            {
                "path": "nBoDuqWRRoZ3LvU1wO",
                "user": "user1"
            }
        ],
        "key2": [
            {
                "path": "fwefwfewfwf",
                "user": "user2"
            },
            {
                "path": "gfdgdfg",
                "user": "user2"
            }
        ]
    }
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

Thursday 08 April 2021  12:37:07 +0200 (0:00:00.054)       0:00:00.077 ******** 
=============================================================================== 
Show our transformed var ------------------------------------------------ 0.05s
```